# save and serve bundle.js as gzip version only

Tags: html, http, amazon-s3, gzip, cdn

I have a react app and save the bundle.js on a CDN (or S3 for this example)

- on save I run `gzip -9`
- on upload to CDN / S3 i add headers: `Content-Encoding: gzip`

now each time a browser / http client will download the bundle it will get:

```
curl -I https://cdn.example.com/bundle.min.js
HTTP/2 200 
content-type: application/javascript
content-length: 3304735
date: Wed, 27 Feb 2019 22:27:19 GMT
last-modified: Wed, 27 Feb 2019 22:26:53 GMT
content-encoding: gzip
accept-ranges: bytes
```

this works fine if I test this in a browser. my only concern is that now we only save a `gzip` version of the js bundle and users will get it regardless of sending over the `Accept-Encoding: gzip` in the request

I cant think of any issues this will cause for browsers but I might be missing something.

Is it a bad practice to "enforce" gzip in the response for the bundle.js file ?

Answer (score 0):

Its several month late, but the answer may still be relevant to someone trying the same thing.

Pre-compression with high compression settings is something that can help with saving few more percentages of bandwidth on static resources. However, forcing a single encoding may create problem for some users. As per a [study conducted in 2010](https://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/07/12/velocity-forcing-gzip-compression/), ~15% of users with gzip-capable browsers were not sending an appropriate Accept-Encoding request header. The reason being anti-virus software or intermediaries/proxies striping `Accept-Encoding` header to force the server to send the content in plain-text form.

If you need a CDN that covers the gap, [PageCDN](https://pagecdn.com) serves exactly the same purpose, but offers superior brotli-11 compression, and falls back to gzip for browsers that do not support brotli. You do not need to connect to S3 or any external storage. Just connect to your website, github, or manually upload files to CDN and configure the compression level for files.